# Array with less elements being defined

Tags: c, arrays

I am learning C from Kochans book and have struck this array exercise. 
It states `ratingCount[11]`, but i have tried different values to see what happens.

When I put 3 elements in there, the program still seems to accept the values into `ratingCounts[4]` and above?
Can someone explain why this is happening?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    int ratingCount[3], i, response;

    for (i = 1; i <= 10; ++i) 
        ratingCount[i] = 0;

    printf ("Enter your response\n");

    for (i = 1; i <= 20; ++i)
    {
        scanf (" %d", &response);

        if (response < 1 || response > 10)
            printf ("Bad entry \n");
        else
            ++ratingCount[response]; 
    }

    printf ("\n\n Rating\nNumber of Responses\n");

    for (i = 1; i <= 10; ++i)
    {
        printf ("%d\t\t%d\n", i, ratingCount[i]);         
    }
    return 0;
    }
```

Output

```
 Rating
Number of Reponses
1       1
2       1
3       1
4       1
5       1
6       2
7       2
8       4
9       5
10      1
Abort trap: 6
```

Comment: You just discovered **Undefined Behavior**!! Let's have party!

Comment: It's your unlucky day. A buggy program *seems* to work fine.

Comment: @RSahu Not really.. there is some "trap" in the end..

Comment: @EugeneSh. The trap is one manifestation of undefined behavior. Agreed, it does *not* seem to work fine though.

Comment: @EugeneSh., oh yeah. Not such an unlucky day, after all :) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I put 3 elements in there, the program still seems to accept the values into ratingCounts[4] and above? Can someone explain why this is happening?

You are writing into memory beyond the end of memory allocated for your array.  The results of that action are undefined.  There is a good chance that you will overwrite storage for other variables.

Some programming languages provide for an automatic bounds check when accessing an array.  C does not.